# Accessing file using fileget url

Tags: node.js, sharepoint, filehandler, ms-wopi

I am trying to create file handler add in that uses provider hosted application to open custom file.

I have hosted app in heroku and until now i get request body in my application as follows when i open file from sharepoint.

```
{
  resourceid: "https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com",
  culturename: "en-US",
  fileget: "https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/wopi.ashx/files/{fileid}/contents?access_token={token}",
  fileput: "https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/wopi.ashx/files/{fileid}/contents?access_token={token}",
  fileid: "{fileid}",
  client: "SharePoint"
}
```

But when i request to get file content using `fileget` url. It throws 500 error with message
`The URL is invalid for the current user or application.`

What could be the way to access file content.

Answer (score 0):

The URL seem to be correct. 
What you can do is to see the [file's URL properties](http://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/CheckFileInfo.html#file-url-properties) by requesting `CheckFileInfo`.

Example:

```
GET https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/wopi.ashx/files/{fileid}?access_token={token}
```

And have a look at `DownloadUrl` and `FileUrl`. If any of the properties is set, use them to download the file.

Comment: Hi Rocky, When i send request to the url as above. it throws and error. ```{"error_description":"Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException' was thrown."}```. I am using postman

Comment: You might have to compose your own URL using the [discovery XML file](https://onenote.officeapps.live.com/hosting/discovery) of your WOPI client instance. It might be slightly different from the one above. Make sure you have the right endpoint (= correct app name, correct action). Plus, did you also try looking at DownloadUrl and FileUrl as I suggested?

Comment: I didn't get any other properties except those written above.I am very new to sharepoint and could not get what you are actually pointing out. I was following the filehandler docs and was supposed to get activation parameters as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/file-handlers/#activation-parameters)